# Gap under footer

Tags: html, css, footer

I am having huge trouble as to why I have a gap under my footer (I tried a fixed footer but it didn't allow me to scroll the page) if you have an answer, please post it. I am confused.

[image]

Regards.

---

(Thanks to the editor who adds my image, I unfortunately need 10 rep)

Image: http://i.gyazo.com/eed1a75737fd1f80a2160148aac30cff.png

---

I totally forgot about the code! Oh my gosh. I am so embarassed.

```css
footer div.footer-ribbon:before {
  border-right-color: #7f0000;
}
footer div.footer-ribbon:before {
  border-right: 10px solid #7f0000;
  border-top: 16px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  left: -10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 7px;
}
footer div.container div.row > div {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
footer div.footer-ribbon {
  background: #cc0000;
  margin: -100px 0 0 30px;
  padding: 10px 20px 6px;
  position: absolute;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 700;
}
footer div.footer-ribbon span {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 700;
}
footer {
  background: #121214;
  border-top: 4px solid #1F1F1F;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 80px 0 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<footer id="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="footer-ribbon" style="right: 0">
        <h3 class="title" style="margin: 0;padding: 5px 10px">Thank <span>You</span></h3>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-copyright">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <p>&copy; Copyright 2015 by Breezer Servers. All Rights Reserved.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 pull-right">
          <nav id="footer-menu">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="http://www.breezerservers.com/careers/">Careers</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="http://www.breezerservers.com/faq/">FAQ's</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="http://www.breezerservers.com/tos/">Terms of Service</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="http://www.breezerservers.com/sponsorship/">Apply for Sponsorship</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please add some code or a fiddle to help us, help you

Comment: If you need an answer in a hurry, you can hire a developer. We're here to help, not be at your beck and call.

Comment: @ochi Thank you for letting me know. I totally forgot.

Comment: nor from the footer, probably from that chatbox you have

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that someone added the space at the bottom of the footer so that the third party chat application won't cover up your footer links.  If you remove the space at the bottom you will need to modify the position of the chat overlay.

To remove the gap you will need to modify the following CSS:

```
footer div.container div.row > div {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

The margin is adding 25px at the bottom of your footer.  Changing the CSS so that the margin no longer exists will solve your initial problem:

```
footer div.container div.row > div {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

To cover any other edge cases from not being able to see your entire code also add the following to your CSS:

`html, body, ul{margin:0;}`

As I mentioned I suspect that this will cause your chat box to cover your footer links.

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code it's hard to guess.  Also add the following to the bottom of your CSS.  This should cover the rest of the possible cases of what it might be: html,body, ul{margin:0;}

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong. My solution worked.

Thanks for all the help. I appreciate it.

Before:

```css
footer {
  background: #121214;
  border-top: 4px solid #1F1F1F;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 80px 0 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

After:
I changed position: relative; to position: absolute and added width: 100%;

```css
footer {
    background: #121214;
    border-top: 4px solid #1F1F1F;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    padding: 80px 0 0;
 padding-bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

It worked perfectly.

Comment: why having `padding-bottom: 0;` duplicated?